# Add autonumber field to query that returns more than 5000 records

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

Adding auto-number field in that query makes ms-access not responding. I used 
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM .....), * FROM ...
My query has non-unique value in every column. I just want to add 1,2,3,4,... in a new column. Please help me solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, missed the *query* part for no known reason, so here is a completely different answer ...

Use this function which reads the records once only and then stores the IDs in a collection that is much faster to look up:

```
Public Function RowCounter( _
  ByVal strKey As String, _
  ByVal booReset As Boolean, _
  Optional ByVal strGroupKey As String) _
  As Long

' Builds consecutive RowIDs in select, append or create query
' with the possibility of automatic reset.
' Optionally a grouping key can be passed to reset the row count
' for every group key.
'
' Usage (typical select query):
'   SELECT RowCounter(CStr([ID]),False) AS RowID, *
'   FROM tblSomeTable
'   WHERE (RowCounter(CStr([ID]),False) <> RowCounter("",True));
'
' Usage (with group key):
'   SELECT RowCounter(CStr([ID]),False,CStr[GroupID])) AS RowID, *
'   FROM tblSomeTable
'   WHERE (RowCounter(CStr([ID]),False) <> RowCounter("",True));
'
' The Where statement resets the counter when the query is run
' and is needed for browsing a select query.
'
' Usage (typical append query, manual reset):
' 1. Reset counter manually:
'   Call RowCounter(vbNullString, False)
' 2. Run query:
'   INSERT INTO tblTemp ( RowID )
'   SELECT RowCounter(CStr([ID]),False) AS RowID, *
'   FROM tblSomeTable;
'
' Usage (typical append query, automatic reset):
'   INSERT INTO tblTemp ( RowID )
'   SELECT RowCounter(CStr([ID]),False) AS RowID, *
'   FROM tblSomeTable
'   WHERE (RowCounter("",True)=0);
'
' 2002-04-13. Cactus Data ApS. CPH
' 2002-09-09. Str() sometimes fails. Replaced with CStr().
' 2005-10-21. Str(col.Count + 1) reduced to col.Count + 1.
' 2008-02-27. Optional group parameter added.
' 2010-08-04. Corrected that group key missed first row in group.

  Static col      As New Collection
  Static strGroup As String

  On Error GoTo Err_RowCounter

  If booReset = True Then
    Set col = Nothing
  ElseIf strGroup <> strGroupKey Then
    Set col = Nothing
    strGroup = strGroupKey
    col.Add 1, strKey
  Else
    col.Add col.Count + 1, strKey
  End If

  RowCounter = col(strKey)

Exit_RowCounter:
  Exit Function

Err_RowCounter:
  Select Case Err
    Case 457
      ' Key is present.
      Resume Next
    Case Else
      ' Some other error.
      Resume Exit_RowCounter
  End Select

End Function
```

Please study the in-line documentation for typical usages including that of yours.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But what I want is "I run a query. The query adds auto-number field". I think I cannot add auto-number field in the design view of a query. I mean like adding auto-number field in table.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll mark it in my mind for later use. Now I'm OK with my method. My method is 1. Create a blank table with same heading as query + auto-number field (ID) as your idea. 2. Run query and the query append to the created table. I used a form for this process. On form load, table contents will be removed, query will run and append to blank table. Then I use the table. Thank you for your idea to add auto-number field in the table.